# RSS Viewer does not work on publishing the page

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I used RSS viewer Web part for RSS feeds. This works well in edit mode and showing all the feeds. But as I published the page, this web part does not able to retrieve feeds from the respective site and keeps on searching for the feeds. 
So, Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://jaredmatfess.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/sharepoint-february-2013-cu-cod-breaks-the-rss-viewer-webpart/

Apparently the Feb 2013 critical update has a bug which breaks the RSS Viewer Webpart on non-anonymous sites. May fix the prob you are having!